1950s? color movie about the search for a black or blue rose
1950s? color movie about finding a black or blue rose
Group of knights(?) searching for a blue or black rose
Memorable scene: The group makes camp for the night, trees come alive and attack them. Kind of cheesy rubber tree costumes

Sounds like the Italian version of The Thief of Bagdad from 1961. From an IMDb review:

The story concerns a prince, played by he-man Steve Reeves, who must pass seven tests in order to find a legendary blue rose and thus save the life of a comatose princess, win her hand in marriage and the kingdom.

You can see the scene where a group of men armed with swords fights moving trees here:




You've nailed it again. 2 for 2!
Thanks
